# Is there a name for $A^TA$, or equivalently, $A^*A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in K^{n\times n}$ with $K=\mathbb{C} \lor K=\mathbb{R}$. I'm looking for the name of the term $A^T A$ (if $K=\mathbb{R}$) or rather $A^*A$ (if $K=\mathbb{C}$).

It appears rather often:

1. In the operator norm of $||A||_{2\to 2}$
2. In linear least squares
3. In the pseudo inverse

And probably many more cases. However, I've never seen it being named... does it have name? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Gramian matrix [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix).